# Wait for the process to get the value in variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to this and trying to learn and understand. I have a function that returns me some data after parsing a csv. ( takes some time to fetch).

```
async function try_123(callback){
  let returnList = []
  csv.parseFile(csv, {headers : true})
     .on('data',(data)=>{
         returnList.push(data['value1'].trim())
     })
     .on('end',()=>{
         callback(Math.max.apply(Math, returnList.map(Number)))
     })
}
```

Now I am trying to call the function using :

```
var val1_Max;
await try123(function(returnValue) {
  console.log(returnValue);
  val1_Max = returnValue;
});
console.log(val1_Max);
```

Here, `console.log(val1_Max)` is returned as undefined. Is there something that I am missing here to get the assigned value. What I want is for func try123 to finish before moving forward to any other process. Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the first function within a promise, like so:

```js
function try_123() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let returnList = []
    csv.parseFile(csv, {headers : true})
     .on('data',(data)=>{
         returnList.push(data['value1'].trim())
     })
     .on('end',()=>{
         return resolve(Math.max.apply(Math, returnList.map(Number)))
     })
  }
}
```

Then, in your main function, you can do `var val1_Max = await try_123()` within an `async` function.

So, your full script would be the following

```js
function try_123() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let returnList = []
    csv.parseFile(csv, {headers : true})
     .on('data',(data)=>{
         returnList.push(data['value1'].trim())
     })
     .on('end',()=>{
         return resolve(Math.max.apply(Math, returnList.map(Number)))
     })
  }
}
async function run() {
   var val1_Max = await try_123()
   console.log(val1_Max)
}
run()
```

Comment: Here, what I want to do is assign it to a global variable and not as not in the local one. So that if I console.log(val1_Max) after run(), it should have that value, currently that is coming as undefined.

Comment: The `run` function can encase all your code, (except functions). Then, just start the script with `run()`

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing callbacks and promise. If you're using async/await then you can use return a promise in your `try_123` function. So you can wrap your function call inside an async `iife` and await the function call like so:

```
function try_123() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let returnList = []
    csv.parseFile(csv, {headers : true})
     .on('data',(data)=>{
         returnList.push(data['value1'].trim())
     })
     .on('end',()=>{
         return resolve(Math.max.apply(Math, returnList.map(Number)))
     })
  }
} 

(async function(){
  var val1_Max = await try123();
  console.log(val1_Max);
})()
```

Comment: I tried this and ended up with the same issue. 

When I am assigning a variable like `var val_max1;
(async function(){
  val_max1 = await try123();
})()

console.log(val_max1);`
Still it prints it as undefined.

Comment: Yeah...the whole point to put that variable inside async fn is so that you can access it synchronously after the value is set. Why are you accessing it outside?

Comment: I need this data before the other process, that is why I need to access it outside.